# Most sensitive hearing human ever measured?

Tags: human-biology

The Fletcher Munsen curve shows the lowest spl that humana can hear is -6db around 4 KHz.I assume this curve is average obtained from measuring many people.

My question is,what is the most extreme hearing in terms of threshold spl ever measured? What person holds the record for most sensitive hearing?